# Websphere SOAP over JMS location and IllegalArgumentException: protocol = jms host = null

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jms, websphere

We have a JAXWS webservice that will receive SOAP message over JMS. The webservice is installed on a Websphere 8 server and an MQ queue will be installed on another server, a third server will receive SOAP message over HTTP and send them to the MQ queue. The problem I have is that when I deploy the webservice on Websphere I get the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = jms host = null
at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:163) ~[na:6.0]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.EndpointAddress.chooseProxy(EndpointAddress.java:186) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.EndpointAddress.<init>(EndpointAddress.java:134) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parsePort(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:515) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseService(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:483) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:461) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:328) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.getWSDLPort(EndpointFactory.java:746) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:254) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:158) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:577) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560) ~[webservices-rt-2.3.jar:2.3]
[...]
```

It seem to be related to a problem with the endpoint adress in the WSDL but I'm not exactly sure what should be in that field. Here is what I used :

```
<service name="OrderService">
<port name="OrderAsyncPortType" binding="tns:OrderPortTypeBinding">
<soap:address location="jms:jndi:jms/OrderQueue?jndiConnectionFactoryName=jms/OrderConnectionFactory&amp;targetService=OrderAsyncPortType"/>
</port>
</service>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should check your JMS component configuration that the connection factory is set to a correct conn  show us the code ?

Comment: I can't show the code because it is using a internal framework which will eventually be open source but for now is confidential.